# Is there any way to use .gdoc (google doc files) in pydrive?

Tags: python-3.x, google-docs, google-colaboratory, pydrive

I've been attempting for a while now to get pydrive to accept my google doc files now. I've tried to find ways to convert .gdoc's to .docx's so I can use the python-docx package to read them, since all the packages I have found have been really confusing to try and learn to use.

Basically want I'm attempting to do is to read a table from a google doc and use the data in that table to create a dictionary with things such as `{'xsubject': {'Monday': 'Assignment...}...}`. If there is a package that can just read google docs tables, I guess that would be useful. Any help would be appreciated.

Also, since I am working in colab the google docs api quickstart does not seem to work for me. It attempts to open a localhost page and it doesn't show anything nor does it attempt to load.